# LinkedList using iterator

Tags: java

im trying to add pickels between lettuce and chicken in my linkedlist and print out the final product which should be:

**Bread1,mustard,lettuce,pickels,chicken,tomato,Bread2,end...**

However, the program only prints out: **mustard,chicken,Bread2,end...**

can someone explain to me the error?

```
public class LinkedList
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

    List<String> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>();

    String strOutput="";

    myLinkedList.add("Bread1");
    myLinkedList.add("mustard");
    myLinkedList.add("lettuce");
    myLinkedList.add("chicken");
    myLinkedList.add("tomato");
    myLinkedList.add("Bread2");

    ListIterator<String> lit = myLinkedList.listIterator();

    while (lit.hasNext())
    {
      String str = lit.next();
      if (myLinkedList.equals("lettuce"))
      {
         lit.add("pickels");
      }
      strOutput += (lit.next().toString() + ",") ;
    }
    strOutput += ("end...\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: `lit.next().toString()` why do you call `#next` a second time? `if (myLinkedList.equals("lettuce"))` you could also write `if(false)`, so please think about what you're doing  there.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors, and both are related to the lack of using the `str` variable:

```
while (lit.hasNext())
{
  String str = lit.next();
  if (str.equals("lettuce")) // <-- Use str, not myLinkedList
  {
     lit.add("pickels");
  }
  strOutput += (str + ",") ; // <-- Use str, not lit.next()
}
```

Note that `pickels` will not be returned by the `Listiterator`. See javadoc of [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28E%29):

> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). **The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by `next()`**, if any, and after the element that would be returned by `previous()`, if any. (If the list contains no elements, the new element becomes the sole element on the list.) The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to `next` would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to `previous` would return the new element. (This call increases by one the value that would be returned by a call to `nextIndex` or `previousIndex`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some value in middle of a list, you should use `add(index,object)` method.

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"));
 int index = list.indexOf("Banana"); //indexOf() to find the position of Banana
 list.add(index, "Blueberry"); // insert Blueberry before Banana
 System.out.println(list);  //Apple, Blueberry, Banana, Cherry
```

you are calling `next()` twice in one iteration. Every time when you invoke `next()` it gives the next object of the iteration (in this case String). So store the `next()` value in an appropriate variable and use it later if required.

Answer (score 0):

This Should totally do what you need :). Hope it helps!

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Program
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

List<String> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>();

myLinkedList.add("Bread1");
myLinkedList.add("mustard");
myLinkedList.add("lettuce");
myLinkedList.add("chicken");
myLinkedList.add("tomato");
myLinkedList.add("Bread2");

int index = myLinkedList.indexOf("lettuce"); 
myLinkedList.add(index + 1, "pickels"); 
for(String strOutput: myLinkedList){
        System.out.print(strOutput + ",");
 }
}
}
```